# What is the latest in password hash algorithm/data encryption for mysql?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, security

Having me know little about cryptography, I am trying to find the best approach to hash a user password in some `vb.net winform` application; then store it in online `mysql` db.
I found lots of posts about the topic but can't figure out which one is the best approach.

I reach [this MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx) but still can't be sure if I can use it.

I can't where to enter some random key, it is generated automatically by the function.

So my question is , is this a solid function for password hash?
Any alternatives?

Thank you

The code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography



Class AesExample

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Try

            Dim original As String = "Here is some data to encrypt!"

            ' Create a new instance of the Aes
            ' class.  This generates a new key and initialization 
            ' vector (IV).
            Using myAes As Aes = Aes.Create()

                ' Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
                Dim encrypted As Byte() = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, myAes.Key, myAes.IV)

                ' Decrypt the bytes to a string.
                Dim roundtrip As String = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV)

                'Display the original data and the decrypted data.
                Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", original)
                Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", roundtrip)
            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub 'Main

    Shared Function EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal Key() As Byte, ByVal IV() As Byte) As Byte()
        ' Check arguments.
        If plainText Is Nothing OrElse plainText.Length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `ehash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

[NIST](https://www.nist.gov) currently recommends [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) for a password verifier.

See:

- NIST [Recommendation for Password-Based Key Derivation](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-132.pdf)
- NIST Special Publication 800-63B: ([Digital Identity Guidelines](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf)
  )
- [Toward Better Password Requirements](http://www.slideshare.net/jim_fenton/toward-better-password-requirements) by Jim Fenton

Comment: Thank you so much @zaph, If you can kindly post a link to implementation in vb.net that would be great. Thanks

Comment: .NET [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx), is PBKDF2 it's just that MS likes to add confusion.